# How to specify the type of a Class type

Tags: objective-c

I am currently trying to define a method, that takes a `Class` as argument, that is a subclass of a specific type. My current implementation is:

```
- (void)methodThatNeedsAClassOfSpecialTypeAsInput:(Class)inClass {}
```

Taking `NSString` as an example base class, I have tried `NSString.Class` and `[NSString class]` to specify the arguments class, but

```
- (void)methodThatNeedsAClassOfSpecialTypeAsInput:([NSString class])inClass { }
```

does not compile with `Parse issue: Expected a type`.

So the question is: is is possible to make an `Class` arguments type explicit?

Or in other words: I want my methods signatures semantic to say: I can take a `NSString class`, an only a `NSString class` as argument.

**EDIT:**

The answer is: No.

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it:

```
[NSString class]
```

**EDIT** (after question updated):

This is how the method is defined and declared:

```
- (void)methodThatNeedsAClassOfSpecialTypeAsInput:(Class)inClass { }
```

But it is called like this:

```
[someObject methodThatNeedsAClassOfSpecialTypeAsInput:[NSString class]];
```

Comment: @ShallowThought Well all I can say is that's how it's done.  The error must be something different.  If you update your question with the full compiler error message (using the code in my answer) then we can make some progress.

Comment: My problem is the definition of the class. Not calling it. Sorry for being mistakable..

Comment: Then what you had should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong. Method declaration was right

```
- (void)methodThatNeedsAClassOfSpecialTypeAsInput:(Class)inClass;
```

Than, in place you call it

```
[obj methodThatNeedsAClassOfSpecialTypeAsInput:[NSString class]];
```

If, in implementation you need to be guarantee, that your `inClass` is `NSString`, you can use

```
if([inClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
     //Do whatever you need
}
```